# python/pandas - substring replacement using regular expression

Tags: python, pandas

I have inherited an old code file that has the following code. It seems the last line of the code below is removing all the open `(` and close `)` parentheses, and `-` character from the phone number field.

**Question**: But why it is using `regex='\('` in `.replace(regex='\(',value='')` part of that last line? Some other online examples (such as [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and [here](https://appdividend.com/2020/06/10/python-regex-replace-how-to-replace-string-in-python/)) I have seen don't seem to use `regex` keyword in their replacement function. What `regex='\('` is doing in the replace function here?

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd
import re

pw = dbutils.secrets.get(scope='SomeScope',key='sql')
engine = sq.create_engine('mssql+pymssql://SERVICE.Databricks.NONPUBLICETL:'+pw+'MyAzureSQL.database.windows.net:1433/TEST', isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")

pandas_df = pd.read_sql('select * from SQLTable1', con=engine)

pandas_df['MOBILE_PHONE'].replace(regex='\(',value='').replace(regex='\)',value='').replace(regex='\-',value='').str.strip()
```

Comment: The links that you provided are related to `re` package or to `string.replace()` method. But in the inherited code, the replace() method is refering to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html , see `regex` keyword.

Comment: @MarcelPreda So, in `replace(regex='\)',value='')` is it saying: my regex pattern is `\)`. So find all substrings that match this pattern ( close parenthesis in this case) and remove it (i.e., replace it with empty string)?

Comment: yes it is the behavior in your case: everything that matches with `regex`, is replaced by `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding precision depends on experience, logic and mastery of syntax. Its like mastery of normal language. The answer you adapted achieves exactly what the code below does

```
df['MOBILE_PHONE2'] = df['MOBILE_PHONE'].str.replace('[^\d]','',regex=True)
```

**Explanation**

`\d` is regex for digits

`[^]` is regex for everything except

`[^\d]` everything except digits

So, using the pandas API, I replace everything except digits in the string with nothing

Outcome

```
    MOBILE_PHONE  MOBILE_PHONE2
0  (425) 555-1234    4255551234
```

Comment: A good one liner with nice explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the `replace` function has changed.

Replace your last line by:

```
df['MOBILE_PHONE2'] = df['MOBILE_PHONE'].replace('[()-]', '', regex=True).str.strip()
print(df)

# Output
     MOBILE_PHONE MOBILE_PHONE2
0  (425) 555-1234   425 5551234
```

Replace `(` or `)` or `-` by `''`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex keyword as a boolean to tell .replace() whether to interpret the string as regex or as the regular expression itself